# Xamarin.Forms: Trying to implement Restful API, but the app keeps crashing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am trying to build cross platform app by using Xamarin.Forms framework. I have been working on displaying a dummy Restful API into my app but the app keeps crashing when I fire up the following page. Could you please help me? This will be huge step for me if I can figure this out. Thank you!

This is my view page: 
**ApiPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.ApiPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="postsListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the code behind:
**ApiPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ApiPage : ContentPage
    {
        private const string Url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        private ObservableCollection<Post> _posts;
        public ApiPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(content);
            _posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>(posts);
            postsListView.ItemsSource = _posts;

            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        void OnAdd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void OnUpdate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void OnDelete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is the console output but doesn't tell anything:

```
11-04 18:12:09.430 D/Mono    ( 4185): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
11-04 18:12:09.431 D/Mono    ( 4185): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
11-04 18:12:09.521 W/art     ( 4185): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.CellRenderer_RendererHolder
11-04 18:12:12.450 D/Mono    ( 4185): Assembly Ref addref MyApp[0x9e1a6480] -> Newtonsoft.Json[0xb030b7c0]: 2
11-04 18:12:12.576 D/Mono    ( 4185): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Security[0xad5563a0] -> System[0x9e1a78c0]: 14
An unhandled exception occured.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that is an issue between Ssl page certificate and Android OS you can fix this by doing next steps

1. Be sure that you have the reference for System.Net.Http assenbly on you project, 
   1) double click on "References" folder under your Android app project 
   2) check that you have selected "System.Net.Http" selected on "All" tab
   [image: reference]

Step 2: Verify that you're using Native Http Handler and Native SSL/TLS impl.
1) Double click on Xamarin Android project to open project settings
2) Under "Build/Android Build -> General" Section verify that you have correct Native option Selected for both "HttpClient impl" & "SSL/TLS impl" as follow
[image: native impl]